# Shopify App Extension Suddenly Stopped Running Locally By Failing To Push Theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-app-extension

I'm developing a Shopify app extension and I have edited my code numerous times and deployed it but recently I tried running my code locally with "npm run dev" in the cli it started up the dev environment successfully but when it gets to the section of Pushing theme files to App Ext. it fails with an error. Below is the full cli output

```
$ npm run dev 

> wishpo-dev-app@1.0.0 dev
> shopify app dev

╭─ info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│                                                                                            │
│  Using these settings:                                                                     │
│                                                                                            │
│    • Org:          Uniwishes                                                               │
│    • App:          wishpo                                                                  │
│    • Dev store:    blueclothers.myshopify.com                                              │
│    • Update URLs:  Not yet configured                                                      │
│                                                                                            │
│   You can pass `--reset` to your command to reset your app configuration.                  │
│                                                                                            │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

12:44:14 │ web-backend  │
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ > shopify-app-template-node@1.0.0 dev
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ > cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js --ignore ./frontend
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │                                                                                                                     
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │ > shopify-frontend-template-react@1.0.0 dev                                                                         
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │ > vite                                                                                                              
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │                                                                                                                     
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ [nodemon] 2.0.22
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`                                                                        
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*                                                                                     
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json                                                                          
12:44:14 │ web-backend  │ [nodemon] starting `node index.js`                                                                                  
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │   VITE v4.4.4  ready in 449 ms
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │
12:44:14 │ web-frontend │   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:54725/
12:44:15 │ web-backend  │ [shopify-api/WARNING] Loading REST resources for API version 2023-04, which doesn't match the default 2023-07       
12:44:15 │ web-backend  │ [shopify-api/INFO] version 7.5.0, environment Node v20.9.0                                                          
12:44:21 │ extensions   │
12:44:21 │ extensions   │ --------- Pushing theme files to App Ext. Host (51554b-LAPTOP-CC1QQ4AP) (#163606987062) on
blueclothers.myshopify.com
12:44:21 │ extensions   │ Pushing theme...     0%                                                                                             
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┏━━ Error
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ X Cloning into 'C:/Users/M/AppData/Local/Temp/d20231213-17880-7mijze'...
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ remote: Enumerating objects: 9974, done.
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1)
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   0% (1/9974)
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   1% (100/9974)
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   2% (200/9974), 132.00 KiB | 234.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   2% (233/9974), 156.00 KiB | 113.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   3% (300/9974), 156.00 KiB | 113.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   4% (399/9974), 156.00 KiB | 113.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   5% (499/9974), 156.00 KiB | 113.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   5% (551/9974), 348.00 KiB | 133.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   6% (599/9974), 348.00 KiB | 133.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   7% (699/9974), 348.00 KiB | 133.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   7% (783/9974), 348.00 KiB | 133.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   8% (798/9974), 500.00 KiB | 159.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:   9% (898/9974), 500.00 KiB | 159.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  10% (998/9974), 500.00 KiB | 159.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  11% (1098/9974), 636.00 KiB | 174.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  11% (1111/9974), 676.00 KiB | 143.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  11% (1194/9974), 804.00 KiB | 152.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  12% (1197/9974), 804.00 KiB | 152.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  12% (1209/9974), 852.00 KiB | 145.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  12% (1243/9974), 948.00 KiB | 126.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  13% (1297/9974), 1.00 MiB | 140.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  13% (1317/9974), 1.20 MiB | 155.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  13% (1387/9974), 1.36 MiB | 131.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  13% (1392/9974), 1.37 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  14% (1397/9974), 1.37 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  14% (1409/9974), 1.37 MiB | 114.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  14% (1481/9974), 1.56 MiB | 115.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1497/9974), 1.56 MiB | 115.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1547/9974), 1.67 MiB | 119.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1547/9974), 1.75 MiB | 88.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1550/9974), 1.78 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1570/9974), 1.81 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1581/9974), 1.89 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  15% (1592/9974), 1.97 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  16% (1596/9974), 1.97 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  16% (1604/9974), 2.01 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  16% (1617/9974), 2.09 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  16% (1639/9974), 2.14 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  16% (1674/9974), 2.20 MiB | 61.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  17% (1696/9974), 2.20 MiB | 61.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  17% (1716/9974), 2.24 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  17% (1782/9974), 2.33 MiB | 60.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  17% (1789/9974), 2.40 MiB | 57.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1796/9974), 2.40 MiB | 57.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1804/9974), 2.42 MiB | 54.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1821/9974), 2.46 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1838/9974), 2.47 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1845/9974), 2.50 MiB | 37.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1855/9974), 2.52 MiB | 32.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1866/9974), 2.56 MiB | 27.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  18% (1889/9974), 2.60 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1896/9974), 2.60 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1920/9974), 2.64 MiB | 30.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1934/9974), 2.65 MiB | 31.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1960/9974), 2.70 MiB | 35.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1979/9974), 2.75 MiB | 31.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1983/9974), 2.77 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1986/9974), 2.79 MiB | 27.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  19% (1994/9974), 2.82 MiB | 28.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (1995/9974), 2.82 MiB | 28.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2007/9974), 2.87 MiB | 31.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2011/9974), 2.93 MiB | 32.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2025/9974), 2.96 MiB | 31.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2053/9974), 3.03 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2061/9974), 3.08 MiB | 49.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2065/9974), 3.09 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  20% (2078/9974), 3.12 MiB | 44.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  21% (2095/9974), 3.18 MiB | 49.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  21% (2129/9974), 3.26 MiB | 61.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2195/9974), 3.45 MiB | 83.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2196/9974), 3.45 MiB | 83.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2223/9974), 3.51 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2229/9974), 3.57 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2233/9974), 3.58 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  22% (2272/9974), 3.71 MiB | 82.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  23% (2295/9974), 3.78 MiB | 81.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  23% (2309/9974), 3.83 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  23% (2339/9974), 3.91 MiB | 74.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  23% (2353/9974), 3.97 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  23% (2367/9974), 4.06 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  24% (2394/9974), 4.06 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  24% (2416/9974), 4.14 MiB | 82.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  24% (2433/9974), 4.17 MiB | 76.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  24% (2453/9974), 4.26 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  24% (2477/9974), 4.34 MiB | 71.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  25% (2494/9974), 4.38 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  25% (2504/9974), 4.42 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  25% (2546/9974), 4.52 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  25% (2580/9974), 4.64 MiB | 89.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  26% (2594/9974), 4.64 MiB | 89.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  26% (2621/9974), 4.71 MiB | 92.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  26% (2635/9974), 4.81 MiB | 97.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  26% (2637/9974), 4.86 MiB | 89.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  26% (2672/9974), 4.90 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  27% (2693/9974), 4.90 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2793/9974), 4.96 MiB | 83.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2818/9974), 5.00 MiB | 79.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2861/9974), 5.10 MiB | 75.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2868/9974), 5.18 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2878/9974), 5.22 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2884/9974), 5.28 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  28% (2892/9974), 5.31 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  29% (2893/9974), 5.34 MiB | 62.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  29% (2905/9974), 5.37 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  29% (2922/9974), 5.44 MiB | 55.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  29% (2963/9974), 5.51 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  30% (2993/9974), 5.55 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  30% (3020/9974), 5.55 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  30% (3091/9974), 5.64 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  31% (3092/9974), 5.64 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  31% (3164/9974), 5.69 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  32% (3192/9974), 5.74 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  32% (3231/9974), 5.77 MiB | 68.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  33% (3292/9974), 5.86 MiB | 71.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  33% (3319/9974), 5.86 MiB | 71.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  33% (3352/9974), 5.95 MiB | 79.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  33% (3355/9974), 5.96 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  33% (3367/9974), 6.01 MiB | 68.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  34% (3392/9974), 6.11 MiB | 67.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  34% (3409/9974), 6.11 MiB | 67.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  34% (3472/9974), 6.22 MiB | 74.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  35% (3491/9974), 6.22 MiB | 74.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  35% (3553/9974), 6.28 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  36% (3591/9974), 6.37 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  36% (3596/9974), 6.37 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  36% (3619/9974), 6.44 MiB | 79.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  36% (3651/9974), 6.49 MiB | 80.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  36% (3671/9974), 6.64 MiB | 90.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  37% (3691/9974), 6.68 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  37% (3720/9974), 6.75 MiB | 90.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  37% (3779/9974), 6.89 MiB | 105.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3791/9974), 6.97 MiB | 112.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3797/9974), 7.04 MiB | 125.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3823/9974), 7.15 MiB | 121.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3848/9974), 7.19 MiB | 111.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3882/9974), 7.23 MiB | 97.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  38% (3888/9974), 7.35 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3890/9974), 7.35 MiB | 93.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3907/9974), 7.43 MiB | 79.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3921/9974), 7.47 MiB | 76.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3960/9974), 7.53 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3976/9974), 7.55 MiB | 61.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3982/9974), 7.61 MiB | 55.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  39% (3989/9974), 7.64 MiB | 54.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (3990/9974), 7.67 MiB | 50.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (3999/9974), 7.69 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (4031/9974), 7.75 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (4036/9974), 7.82 MiB | 51.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (4047/9974), 7.87 MiB | 55.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  40% (4086/9974), 7.99 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  41% (4090/9974), 7.99 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  41% (4147/9974), 8.04 MiB | 68.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  42% (4190/9974), 8.09 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  42% (4195/9974), 8.18 MiB | 85.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  42% (4246/9974), 8.32 MiB | 98.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  43% (4289/9974), 8.36 MiB | 99.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  43% (4299/9974), 8.36 MiB | 99.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  43% (4328/9974), 8.46 MiB | 104.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  43% (4361/9974), 8.58 MiB | 110.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  43% (4383/9974), 8.71 MiB | 109.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4389/9974), 8.79 MiB | 116.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4397/9974), 8.86 MiB | 112.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4411/9974), 8.98 MiB | 113.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4426/9974), 9.04 MiB | 118.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4433/9974), 9.14 MiB | 104.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4443/9974), 9.18 MiB | 102.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4451/9974), 9.25 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4461/9974), 9.32 MiB | 76.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  44% (4465/9974), 9.33 MiB | 65.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  45% (4489/9974), 9.36 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  45% (4507/9974), 9.39 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  45% (4515/9974), 9.43 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  45% (4535/9974), 9.43 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  45% (4553/9974), 9.54 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  46% (4589/9974), 9.58 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  46% (4608/9974), 9.63 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  46% (4676/9974), 9.68 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4688/9974), 9.72 MiB | 61.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4736/9974), 9.75 MiB | 64.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4741/9974), 9.85 MiB | 80.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4751/9974), 9.89 MiB | 75.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4758/9974), 9.96 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  47% (4775/9974), 10.01 MiB | 70.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4788/9974), 10.05 MiB | 70.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4797/9974), 10.11 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4810/9974), 10.16 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4828/9974), 10.23 MiB | 64.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4841/9974), 10.26 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4861/9974), 10.37 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  48% (4867/9974), 10.44 MiB | 64.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  49% (4888/9974), 10.48 MiB | 69.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  49% (4894/9974), 10.53 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  49% (4967/9974), 10.57 MiB | 76.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (4987/9974), 10.64 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (5013/9974), 10.64 MiB | 73.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (5025/9974), 10.76 MiB | 75.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (5046/9974), 10.82 MiB | 80.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (5072/9974), 10.92 MiB | 83.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  50% (5081/9974), 10.96 MiB | 74.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5087/9974), 11.00 MiB | 70.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5087/9974), 11.04 MiB | 78.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5098/9974), 11.12 MiB | 50.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5104/9974), 11.17 MiB | 45.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5110/9974), 11.20 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  51% (5125/9974), 11.26 MiB | 41.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  52% (5187/9974), 11.29 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  52% (5204/9974), 11.29 MiB | 42.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  52% (5275/9974), 11.46 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5287/9974), 11.46 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5294/9974), 11.50 MiB | 58.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5322/9974), 11.50 MiB | 58.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5333/9974), 11.54 MiB | 49.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5336/9974), 11.54 MiB | 49.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5340/9974), 11.57 MiB | 44.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5356/9974), 11.62 MiB | 46.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  53% (5369/9974), 11.65 MiB | 36.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5386/9974), 11.70 MiB | 35.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5407/9974), 11.75 MiB | 39.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5410/9974), 11.78 MiB | 38.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5415/9974), 11.81 MiB | 45.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5422/9974), 11.90 MiB | 57.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5446/9974), 11.96 MiB | 60.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5476/9974), 12.06 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5479/9974), 12.11 MiB | 64.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5481/9974), 12.13 MiB | 49.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  54% (5485/9974), 12.14 MiB | 45.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5486/9974), 12.16 MiB | 39.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5487/9974), 12.18 MiB | 35.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5488/9974), 12.19 MiB | 18.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5490/9974), 12.19 MiB | 18.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5493/9974), 12.24 MiB | 14.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5495/9974), 12.25 MiB | 13.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  55% (5579/9974), 12.32 MiB | 22.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  56% (5586/9974), 12.36 MiB | 26.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  56% (5593/9974), 12.40 MiB | 28.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  56% (5610/9974), 12.46 MiB | 32.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  56% (5618/9974), 12.51 MiB | 50.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  57% (5686/9974), 12.51 MiB | 50.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  57% (5699/9974), 12.62 MiB | 62.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  57% (5701/9974), 12.62 MiB | 62.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ Receiving objects:  57% (5703/9974), 12.66 MiB | 56.00 KiB/s
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ error: 8114 bytes of body are still expected
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ fatal: early EOF
12:47:35 │ extensions   │ ┃ fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┗━━
```

Please can someone help me in debugging this  I don't have an idea of what I'm doing wrong as this was working a few days ago and I'm new to Shopify.

At first i thought it was a connectivity issue but the problem still persisit since yesterday after even using a stronger internet connection